# How can I fix this intent issue?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, optimization, timer

**TL;DR:**

### **How can I give one intent a preference over another?**

If two intents are run at the same time, I want only one of those intents to start.

---

My game has a 20 second timer running in the background service, and when that timer ends, a new activity (game over screen) starts through an intent. The user is pressing buttons to change activities (again, through intent) in those 20 seconds.

The problem is, if the user pushes a button at the same time that the timer ends, the next activity starts rather than the game over screen. Now, the timer is over, and the user is stuck randomly pushing buttons for no reason. How can I fix this? **Is there any way to make sure that the Game Over screen will open up after 20 seconds?**

I haven't provided much code, because it is mainly just starting intents. If you need any detail, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Simple thing to use a flag variable,that maintains the sate of transition,once any intent fired then stop other using that flag.!

Comment: At time of TimerEnd, deactive button listening function that makes button work for 20 sec or so.

Comment: @BASEERULHASSAN How do I disable the onClick? I have about 20 activities, so I won't know which button to disable, so I'll need to disable all of them...Thanks so much

Comment: @FireCandy How do I do that? I have never used flags before in my intents. Do you mind showing me how?

Comment: never used flag variable?

Comment: @FireCandy Sadly, no. I have seen them though and am slightly familiar. How should I do that? Can you please post an answer?

Comment: @BASEERULHASSAN Feel free to post an answer on what you think I should do. I will accept your answer if it works! :-)

Comment: The best thing to do is at 19.9 secs or so, set `myButton.setEnabled(false);`for all the buttons the user can press which you don't want him to

Comment: @ShreyansSheth Can I do that in base activity so that all the buttons get disabled?

Comment: Yeah sounds good. Provided you can access your timer from there

Answer (score 1):

do timer checking on user click event should do it. or you can use flag/boolean to maintain state.

i dont know your code, just use simple conditional if..

```
 if (timer <= 0){
      //open whatever u want and reset timer again..
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I am not really sure what you mean...Thanks so much, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to take a global variable as a flag,
let say `int =  0`
Now initialize it as "0" and on your both intents give condition as below:

```
 if(i == "0"){
    .
    .
    .
    //fire your intent..
i= 1;
    }
```

,And then flush that variable to "0" whenever you want.Hope you got idea.

Comment: But then it will reset right? And I won't be able to go to my next activity after, even if the timer hasn't stopped. Also, isn't this just an int, not a flag? I am confused...Thanks, please let me know

Comment: Also, do I need separate code in timer and in activities with buttons?

Comment: Please read my answer properly,I told you to flush that variable to "0"...!!! now its up to you ,when to reset it.