# Disable all buttons android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity

I asked this question earlier today:

[How can I fix this intent issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238020/how-can-i-fix-this-intent-issue)

If to intents are run at the same time, I only  wanted one of those intents to start. I had a timer running in the background which started an activity at 20 seconds, while the user is constantly switching between activities through buttons.

So, I got a comment suggesting to deactivate my buttons after my timer finished, so that the user cannot try and click both at the same time. **His comment:**

[image]

Now, I have 15 activities that the user is traveling through, so I don't know which button the user will be on to disable. So, what should I do to disable **all** of the buttons in the project? Will this even fix the problem? Because I am technically disabling it after the timer ends...So I am confused on what to do. **How should I disable all of the buttons, and will this even fix the issue?**

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Comment: Where is you timer, in which activity?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't disable all the buttons from a single activity. You can add snippets of code in every activity to do so when a particular intent is passed and then use the `layout.removeView(mybutton)`

Comment: @ShreyansSheth Okay, but would that work? Because my concern is that it wont work because we are removing the buttons after the timer goes off...not before.

Comment: You basically want to disable the activity the user is on after/at 20 secs right?

Comment: @ShreyansSheth Here's my problem. If user clicks on button for next activity at the same time 20 seconds go up, the user just moves to next activity, and timer is gone. Now, user is stuck with no timer...I want to make sure that the game over screen shows up after 20 seconds are up, regardless of what the user does. Maybe I can make all user actions disabled after 19.9 seconds or something? Let me know

Comment: 'disabled after 19.99 seconds' seems fair enough.

Comment: @Ruchir: How about lettting the timer run for 21 seconds and disable it at 20 instead. Would make more sense

Comment: @ShreyansSheth Sorry for the late reply, bad internet. But, I need the timer to run for 20 seconds...So, maybe I can disable it at 19. I like what you're saying, so if you want, post an answer with some more detail in it. I'll mark it best answer for you. If you have any other ideas in mind of what I can do, make sure to include it in your answer!

Comment: Sure. I'll do it in a while. Let's see if you get a better reply till then. I'll also think a little more

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Basically, where is the timer, in which activity?

Comment: @NigamPatro It is in a background service. Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: @ShreyansSheth So far, the only replies I have gotten now are suggesting to do the disabling of buttons and something with flags, although I have no idea what that answer meant... I feel like disabling the buttons may be a bad idea...But, if it is the only option, I'll do it. Let me know! :-)

Comment: Another idea is to somewhat give no functionality to the click property of the button at 19.9 seconds or what be by creating a dummy intent. Meaning keep if empty

Comment: @ShreyansSheth How would I do that? Isn't that the same as the thing we were talking about earlier?

Comment: Won't an if-else work?

Comment: If time <19.9 then new onclick listener blah blah else dummy intent code

Comment: @ShreyansSheth https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7aa58390eb3ebeb54303

Comment: @ShreyansSheth I made a typo, I meant =1, not =19

Comment: Gimme sometime. I'll get back to you in a while. Multitasking

Comment: Can i have your timer code?

Comment: I tried the Tread.sleep(20000) but that would make the UI pause as well. You could even try a while loop. Like while(time<19.999) or something. That's all i can think of with whatever current knowledge i have of your project